# How would initiate requests to an array of links, and then after they have all resolved, render results using Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, axios

I am trying to use `axios` and `express` to get an array of links from a page, harvest data at each link, and display results to the user. The process I'd like to implement is:

1. Run `axios.get(targetPage)`, harvest the links on the target page, save to an array
2. Run run `axios.all` to get a response from link
3. Harvest data from each response
4. Display to user

Below is my `app.get` function:

```
app.get('/search', function (req, res) {
    var context = {};
    context.resources = [];
    var promises = [];
    var year = req.query.year;
    var targetPage = endpoint + year;
    axios.get(targetPage).then(resp => {
        var $ = cheerio.load(resp.data);
        var pages = []
        $('queryStr').each(function (i, ele) { pages.push(endpoint + $(ele).attr("href")) });
        context.links = pages;
        pages.forEach( link => promises.push( axios.get(link) ));
    }).then(axios.all(promises)).then( responses => {
        responses.forEach( resp => {
            var resource = {};
            resource.link = resp.url;
            var $ = cheerio.load(resp.data)
            resource.title = $('query').text()
            context.resources.push(resource);
        })
    }).then( () => {
        res.render('search', context);
    })
})
```

I have verified that the urls in the `pages[]` array are valid.  I have tried calling `res.render` after the first `axios.get` call, and it successfully rendered my response. I have separately tested the logic in the `forEach` and verified that it works for each url. I'm getting an error message at the `then` block immediately following `axios.all`, which states that `responses` returned by `axios.all` is undefined. the Here is the error message:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: If you are running a 'scraper', you should use puppeteer on express.  https://www.toptal.com/puppeteer/headless-browser-puppeteer-tutorial

Comment: Thanks! I didn't anticipate having to do much async wrangling since the pages I'm scraping are static, but even ordering two sets of scrapes has been a headache. It looks like puppeteer abstracts some of that. I appreciate the link.

Answer (score 0):

**[TLDR]**
This is because the function of your first `then` clause doesn't have a `return` statement.

This means there is no successful data passed to the next `then` clause and so on.

`then` chaining requires `return` for each `then` clause.

[**Example**](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining)

Comment: Thanks! It was indeed an issue with the return values of the `then` statements. I had to make sure that every step returned a `Promise`.

Answer (score 0):

There's many problems in my original post, but the main issue was failure to return a `Promise` in each step of my `.then` chain. Below is working code, significantly refactored. I'm sure there's better ways of passing along errors and loading in parallel, so please leave answers and comments with any improvements. In addition to the [resource](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining) linked to by [Nazim Kerimbekov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8306666/nazim-kerimbekov) and [Khoa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3550678/khoa), I recommend [this post](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/javascriptpromises.shtml) for learning how to chain promises.

```
app.get('/pageToRender', function (req, res) {
    var context = {};
    var page1 = req.query.year
    getInitial(page1)
    .then( pages => Promise.all( pages.map( page => { return getResource(page) })))
    .then(resources => { 
        context.resources = resources;
        res.render('pageToRender', context);
    })
    .catch( errors => { console.log(errors) })
})


function getInitial (page) {
    return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
        axios.get(page).then( resp => {
            var pages = []
            var $ = cheerio.load(resp.data)
            $('.mw-content-ltr li a').each(function (i, ele) { pages.push(endpoint + $(ele).attr("href")) });
            console.log(pages);
            resolve(pages);
        }).catch( error => reject(error))
    })
}

function getResource(page) {
    return new Promise ( (resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get(page)
        .then( response => {
            var resource = {};
            resource.link = page;
            var $ = cheerio.load(response.data)
            resource.title = $('.Title').text()
            console.log("resolving resource", resource);
            resolve(resource);          
        }).catch (error => { error })
    })
}
```